# HeidiSQL: access denied but IP not matching

Tags: windows

I just added a new database connection in HeidiSQL, but I can't open it. What I don't understand is that the error popup shows me another IP.

I try to access to 172.31.6.52, but the error shows 172.16.201.232. I've double checked and rewrote credentials.

[image]

Does anybody understand the issue?
Could there have any relation between these IP?

*N.B. I have never seen this IP before.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the client IP address (172.16.201.232, being your computer) with the server address (172.31.6.52).

The error message tells you that your computer is not allowed to connect (or that the password is incorrect).

(For MySQL you'd need [something like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html) `grant all on mydatabase.* to 'root'@'%'` to allow connecting from *any* remote client. Alternatively,  MySQL accepts wildcards in the host name. And as your IP addresses are part of the private range 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255, you might be able to use something like `@'172.16.%.%'`. This will only match IP addresses, not `172.16.some.untrusted.example.com`.)

Comment: Correct! I already had multiple `root` privileges, but not from this (new) host.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but adding some details. After installing HeidiSQL I ran into this issue as well.

I suspected that the software ignored the "Nom ou IP de l'hote". Instead of using 172.31.6.52 it looks like 172.16.201.232 is being used.

You may not have seen the .232 IP address before but probably it's your computers ip-address. You can check by opening a command prompt (cmd.exe) and type "ipconfig". It should be listed there under 'IPv4 Address"

As Arjan posted, probably you need to change the configuration on the server side to allow access if you try to connect from your computer.

It would be nice if the Error message said something like:

```
           ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ┃   Erreur                                                                  ┃
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ├━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┤
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ┃  Authentication request successfully sent to: 172.31.6.52                 ┃
           ┃  A response is received...                                                ┃
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ┃  ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.16.201.232' (using             ┃
           |         password: YES)                                                    ┃
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ├━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┤
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           ┃                                                              [◄  Ok  ►]   ┃
           ┃                                                                           ┃
           └━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┘
```